# Recursion- sum of n natural number

Tags: c++, recursion, callstack, function-definition

function to calculate the sum of n natural number

```
int solve(int n)
{
    if(n==0 or n==1)
    return n;
    int sum=0;

    sum=sum+n;
    solve(n-1);   // gives me wrong output

    return sum;
}

int solve(int n)
{
    if(n==0 or n==1)
    return n;
    int sum=0;

    sum=sum+solve(n-1);  // gives me correct output

    return sum;
}
```

what is the difference in the working or output of both the function as call stack works same in both the cases

Comment: It looks like `solve` returns something pretty important and ignoring what it returns isn't quite right, whaddya think?

Comment: Recursion uses stack for execution. In your first solution you are only doing the sum of the first iteration and invoking the sum function again with a decreased value but not using the returned value.

Comment: Using the second function, `solve(5)` returned `1`. Is this really correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`solve` function in the first method does not have any effect in your program

```
int solve(int n)
{
    if(n==0 or n==1)
    return n;
    int sum=0;

    sum=sum+n;
    solve(n-1);   // has not any effect

    return sum;
}
```

In the second method, returned value will always be 1 while it must return the sum of the numbers, correct code for calculate sum of numbers is:

```
int solve(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;

    int sum = 0;

    sum = n + solve(n - 1);  // change 'sum' with 'n'

    return sum;
}
```

Run:

`solve(5);`

Output:

`5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15`

Answer (score 1):

There are much common in the both functions.

The functions can be called with a negative argument because the parameter type is int. In this case you can get a senseless result.

The type of the variable that accumulates the sum of numbers should be larger than the type int to escape an overflow.

The first function always returns the value of the passed argument in the first recursive call of the function.

This statement

```
solve(n-1);   // gives me wrong output
```

has no effect because the returned value is not used.

The second function always returns either 0 or 1 (provided that a non-negative argument was passed) due to this statement

```
if(n==0 or n==1)
return n;
```

Because in this code snippet

```
int sum=0;

sum=sum+solve(n-1);  // gives me correct output
```

the current value of the argument is not used.

It seems there is a typo and should be written

```
sum = n + solve(n-1);  // gives me correct output
```

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long sum( unsigned int n )
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n + sum( n - 1 );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum( 100 ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5050
```

The return statement in the function can be also written like

```
return n < 2 ? n : n + sum( n - 1 );
```

To decrease the number of recursive calls the function can be rewritten the following way

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long sum( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? n : sum( n - 2 ) + n + n - 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum( 100 ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```